# Macro definition malformed for macro

Tags: c, macros

I have the following macro which is supposed to get a struct `CLEAR_ARG` and set some values to it:

```
#define POLICY_ARG_SET((CLEAR_ARG), ARG1, ARG2, ARG3, ARG4, ARG5, ARG6, ARG7, ARG8) \
    CLEAR_ARG->arg1= ARG1 \
    CLEAR_ARG->arg2 = ARG2; \
    CLEAR_ARG->arg3 = ARG3; \
    CLEAR_ARG->arg4 = ARG4; \
    CLEAR_ARG->arg5 = ARG5; \
    CLEAR_ARG->arg6 = ARG6; \
    CLEAR_ARG->arg7 = ARG7; \
    CLEAR_ARG->arg8 = ARG8;
```

But I get `macro definition malformed for macro` warning for some reason.

I used the macro without the brackets over the `(CLEAR_ARG)`, and set the struct with

```
POLICY_ARG_SET((&clear_arg),...)
```

but I don't want to always worry about the brackets. Why do I get this warning, and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have misplaced the parentheses. In the name and arguments you cannot use them, you need to use them in the definition (the part that gets expanded).

Change your macro to this and it should work:

```
#define POLICY_ARG_SET(CLEAR_ARG, ARG1, ARG2, ARG3, ARG4, ARG5, ARG6, ARG7, ARG8) \
    (CLEAR_ARG)->arg1 = ARG1; \
    (CLEAR_ARG)->arg2 = ARG2; \
    (CLEAR_ARG)->arg3 = ARG3; \
    (CLEAR_ARG)->arg4 = ARG4; \
    (CLEAR_ARG)->arg5 = ARG5; \
    (CLEAR_ARG)->arg6 = ARG6; \
    (CLEAR_ARG)->arg7 = ARG7; \
    (CLEAR_ARG)->arg8 = ARG8;
```

Note, in your example `(CLEAR_ARG)->arg1 = ARG1;` is missing a semi-colon (`;`) as well

Comment: Good catch. It is probably also a good idea to put all of that inside a `do { ... } while (0)` clause, or at least to omit the final `;` to have everything fit more nicely in a "usual" C context.